# Mysql Transactions in a multithreaded c# environment

Tags: c#, mysql

```
public class MysqlDbHandler : IDbHandler
    {
        string connStr = $"...";

        MySqlConnection conn;

        public async Task<DbConnection> ConnectAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                conn = new MySqlConnection( connStr );
                await conn.OpenAsync();
                return conn;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                conn.Close();
                throw;
            }
        }

        public async Task ExecuteNonQuery(MySqlCommand command)
        {
            using (var conn = await ConnectAsync())
            {
                command.Connection = (MySqlConnection)conn;
                using (command)
                {
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }

        public async Task<MySqlDataReader> ExecuteReaderQuery(MySqlCommand command)
        {
            using (var conn = await ConnectAsync())
            {
                command.Connection = (MySqlConnection)conn;
                using (command)
                    return (MySqlDataReader)await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();
            }

        }
}


public abstract class BaseRepository<T>
{
        protected IDbHandler dbHandler;
        protected IList<T> Items;

        protected string UpdateQuery, AddQuery, GetAllQuery;

        protected BaseRepository(IDbHandler dbHandler, string updateQuery, string addQuery, string getAllQuery)
        {
            this.dbHandler = dbHandler ?? throw new ArgumentNullException( nameof( dbHandler ) );
            UpdateQuery = updateQuery ?? throw new ArgumentNullException( nameof( updateQuery ) );
            AddQuery = addQuery ?? throw new ArgumentNullException( nameof( addQuery ) );
            GetAllQuery = getAllQuery ?? throw new ArgumentNullException( nameof( getAllQuery ) );
        }

        public async Task Update(T t)
        {
            var query = UpdateQuery;
            var parameters = BuildParameterList( t );
            var command = NewCommand( query, parameters );
            await dbHandler.ExecuteNonQuery( command );
        }

        protected abstract Dictionary<string, object> BuildParameterList(T t);
        protected MySqlCommand NewCommand(string query) => new MySqlCommand( query );


        protected MySqlCommand NewCommand(string query, Dictionary<string, object> parameters) 
        {
            var cmd = new MySqlCommand( query );
            foreach (var p in parameters)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( p.Key, p.Value );
            return cmd;
        }
}
```

I have a group of repository classes to which I pass in a single instance of `dbHandler` through the constructor. These repository classes themselves have methods that construct command objects and interact with the public dbHandler methods (ExecuteNonQuery, ExecuteReaderQuery) to get a connection and execute the query/command. I need to incorporate transactions into some of these commands, but I am not sure if they will be safe in a multithreaded environment. If one thread opens a connection using ConnectAsync as implemented above, begins a transaction, and starts processing/executing commands, while another thread opens a connection, and executes an unrelated command, that is not intended to be part of that transaction, will that work as intended, or will that subject my code to a race condition where the unrelated command might become part of the transaction under certain conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transaction is associated with the connection it was started on (i.e., the connection object for which `MySqlConnection.BeginTransaction` was called). It will not be used by any other open and active `MySqlConnection` object in the process. (Trying to use the `MySqlTransaction` object with a different `MySqlConnection` would be an error.)

Also note that if you're using MySQL Connector/NET (aka `MySql.Data`), it is a longstanding known issue that asynchronous operations don't actually work: [MySQL bug 70111](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70111). You should switch to an alternative MySQL ADO.NET library, e.g., [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/), to get true asynchronous behaviour.

EDIT: As of 18 Jan 2023, [MySQL bug 70111](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70111) is scheduled to be fixed in version 8.0.33.

Comment: Is there a possibility that the same mysqlconnection will be assigned by the pooling mechanism that manages them?

Comment: Until the `MySqlConnection` is closed/disposed, it's considered to be in use and won't be handed out (by the connection pool) to any other client calling `MySqlConnection.Open`. (Of course, closing it then continuing to use it would be a gross programming error.)